# EditText not resizing in TableLayout

Tags: java, android, fragment, tablelayout

I have the following TableLayout in a Fragment with a heading row of EditTexts that are disabled (used purely for cosmetic purposes result is the same even for TextViews):

```
    <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/table_header_bsight"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/table_heading_bs"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18dp" >

                </EditText>

                //8 More EditTexts defined the same as above
```

The user then uses a button to add additional TableRows to the TableLayout in code using the following.

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    EditText cell = new EditText(getActivity());
    cell.setPadding(30, 15, 30, 15);
    cell.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    cell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
    cell.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    // set up the keyboard so it doesn't go fullscreen
    cell.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    cell.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
    cell.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
            | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
            | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
    row.addView(cell);
    table.addView(row);
```

The problem is the editTexts i have defined in XML don't resize when long text is entered as shown in the following picture where.

[image: See top row with "Remark"]![See top row with "Remark]

I don't know how I am getting two different results by declaring the EditTexts in code or XML.
Can anyone shed some light on why they would have different behaviour?